# UITextView visual clicable feedback is delaying

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have `UITableViewCell` in which i have `UITextView` with data detectors enabled, So when there is a phone number or a emaid address it is considered as link, Everything works fine the only problem what i am facing is that when clicked on that `UITextView` the visual feedback like grey selection doesnt appear all the time mostly shows when long pressed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you written your code in Dispatch, any UI Change will be happen in Dispatch Queue.

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Your Code
    }
```

Comment: No i have not. Code is totally straight forward where when touched it directly goes to its delegate method. `shouldInteractWithURL`

Answer (score 0):

Long press is intended behavior of `UITextView` data detectors, it is there to prevent accidental opening of links and do calls on a single tap.

Comment: Ok but even when u just tap slightly still the call happens but only difference is that you don't see that it is clicked.

Comment: This was not clear from your question. On my device, a single tap and a long press open different system UI to interact with detected data.